# Given a set $A=\{ B \subseteq \mathbb{R}\}$, is this relation $R$ of equivalence?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$A=\{B\subseteq \mathbb{R}\}$$
$$R: (C,D) \in R \iff C\setminus D \text{ or } D\setminus C \text{ is not greater than countable}$$

The question: Is $R$ a relation of equivalence? If it is, what class of equivalence?

It's reflexive: $(C,C) \in R \iff C \setminus C = \emptyset$, which has a cardinality less than countable. As for rest () I'm lost.

Symmetric: $(C,D) \in R \hookrightarrow (D,C) \in R \iff C \setminus D\text{ or } D\setminus C\text{ less than countable } \hookrightarrow C \setminus D \text{ or } D\setminus C \text { less than countable}$

Transitive: $(C\setminus D \text{ or } D\setminus C \text{ less than countable) and (} D\setminus E \text{ or } E\setminus D \text{ less than countable} ) \hookrightarrow (C,E) \in R$

(how can you show if this is last statement is true or not?)

What about the second part of the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symmetry is trivial: $(C,D)\in R$ means either $C\setminus D$ is countable or $D\setminus C$ is countable. Therefore either $D\setminus C$ is countable or $C\setminus D$ is countable and so $(D,C)\in R$.

But Transitivity fails: Consider $C=(-1,0]$, $D=(-1,1)$ and $E=[0,1)$. Then $C\setminus \{1\}=E\setminus D$ so that $(C,D)\in R$ and $(D,E)\in R$. But $C\setminus E=(-1,0)$ and $E\setminus C=(0,1)$. Neither of which are countable. So $(C,E)\not\in R$

Note: I am using "countable" to mean "at most countable"